# Hibernate : Update elements with unique constraint in cascade

Tags: hibernate

In my application, I've a Grid that contains many Cells. These Cells can contain many Parameters.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "template")
public class Grid {

    private Set<Cells> cells = new HashSet<Cells>(0);

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "grid", orphanRemoval=true)
    @Cascade(value = {CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.DELETE})
    public Set<Cell> getCells() {
        return this.cells;
    }

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "cell", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"idcell", "row", "column" })} )
public class Cell {

    private Grid grid;
    private int row
    private int column;
    private Set<Parameter> parameters = new HashSet<Parameters>(0);

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cellidgrid", nullable = false)
    @ForeignKey(name = "coref_cell_grid")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    public Grid getGrid() {
        return this.grid;
    }


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "cell", orphanRemoval=true)
    @Cascade(value = {CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.DELETE})
    public Set<Parameter> getParameters() {
        return this.parameters;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "parameter")
public class Parameter {

    private Cell cell;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parametercell")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @ForeignKey(name = "coref_parameter_cell")
    public Cell getCell() {
        return this.cell;
    }
}
```

There's an unique constraint in database that limits only one Cell for each row and column of the Grid.

If I invert the position of two Cells, the update of the Grid fails because of an unique constraint violation.

Example : Invert the Cell A with position 1, 2 (row 1, column 2) with Cell B that has position 3, 4.

I tried many things but nothing worked. The main solution was :

- remove the two elements from the Grid, flush and add them again or add their clone to the Grid.

Note that the problem could come from the Parameters of the Cells too.

How can I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You have not posted how are you updating the Cells and what exactly code wise you are doing when you mention "add their clone to the Grid".

As per the description when you are updating it, I am assuming you are simply setting properties row and column of the instances in consideration and updating Grid. When Grid cascades the operation it will try to update the first update entry by 3,4 but that entry already exists hence the exception.

When you say you remove both and flush that means you are deleting the entry from database and adding new and that point both are fresh entries hence no exception.

Thats what I can think of must be happening. Hope helps !!!!